# C++ To C# - One little function

Tags: c#, .net, c++, pinvoke

Can you help me to transfer that code to C#?

```
HWND Notepad = FindWindowEx( GetDesktopWindow( ), 0, "Notepad", 0 );

SendMessage( GetDlgItem( Notepad, MB_TYPEMASK ), WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)"Hello Notepad, what's up?" );
```

Thank you in advance

UPDATE:
I want to send key presses to background window.
I don't want to use SendKeys.Send because I want that window to be in background.
SendKeys requires that window is active.

Comment: Simple. Cut + Paste =  Transfer :P

Comment: Wouldn't it be better it you have also highlighted what functionality you want to achieve?

Comment: @Abdul Maqtadir I want to send key presses to background window.
I don't want to use SendKeys.Send because I want that window to be in background.
SendKeys requires that window is active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know such a low level funcionality is not available in WinForms, hence you should call WinApi via pinvoke which will result in almost literal rewrite of this code to c#

Start here

[GetDlgItem](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetDlgItem.html)
[GetDesktopWindow](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetDesktopWindow.html)
[FindWindowEx](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/FindWindowEx.html)